# Replace all files in a directory

Tags: windows

So basically what I'd like to do, is replace all the files in a directory with another file.

Example :
I've got a folder with a.jpg, b.jpg and c.jpg, and a file named d.jpg outside of the folder. What I want to do is :
Copy d.jpg
Past it in the right directory
Rename it a.jpg
Paste it again
Rename it b.jpg
Paste it again
Etc...

I don't know how to do that, I think a .bat file could do that, but how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In  a .bat file, loop *.jpg and copy the new image to the same name;

```
for %%f in ("c:\target\*.jpg") do (
    copy "c:\replacement\d.jpg" "%%f"
)
```

Obviously this irreversibly overwrites all c:\target*.jpg files.